# How to Add external DIV to Append Script by ID to display its link in result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i javascript expert

in my template i used this script which worked perfect to display html used inside append.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft"></div><div id="wrapright">This is text display by append</div></div></div>');
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle result: https://jsfiddle.net/83fbnwe4/7/

### Then whats my problem is ?

i want to do to add my id in my append body html structure.

Example: i have an ID in my template. which is like this:

```
<div id="showlink"><a href="http://example.com"></div>
```

Now how to add this **id showlink** in my append body next to wrapleft so it work to display the link **"example.com"** in result.

I tried this but its not working:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft">'+("#showlink")+'</div><div id="wrapright">This is text display by append</div></div></div>');
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Not Working; `https://jsfiddle.net/83fbnwe4/9/`
i know its wrong because i am not well aware with javascript sntax, it comes as plain text...while i want to display the id showlink `example.com` here. 
fiddle ones is not working but i am just understanding you to how to add that id inside append next to wrapleft so it display the link in result.

to understand you better:
Screenshot: `http://prntscr.com/a4nks7`
Or see 
[to show link by id inside append](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKJvD.jpg)

#### Note:

do not advise me to add the `<div id="showlink"><a href="http://example.com"></div>` directly inside append next to wrapleft like this:
`<div id="wrapleft"><div id="showlink"><a href="http://example.com"></div></div>` I already know this, but i want to add like as above i demonstrated.

I hope someone will figure out the solution: as i explained very well in detail.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/83fbnwe4/10/)?

Comment: @ArmanOzak - Excellent answer Arman, you should have suggested it as a formal answer.

Comment: @ArmanOzak wow man, the same problem that i was looking for..you are the right person which got me correct..your answer is marked as super answer..what can i say big. i KISS you man :p thanks bundles...post your answer so i mark it as answered for you.

Comment: @ArmanOzak man you are a mind master and genius, i spend almost a day on this issue but non of other contributors solve it...you are winner to all of them. thanks.

Comment: John Belly and gibberish, thank you, but it was not an actual answer at that moment. I was just trying to understand what John needed. In the meantime, @PatrickEvans has given a very robust and clever answer (the first one). I think he should get the rep, not me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you want, however, this does show how to append the existing html in the wrapleft div.   If it's not what you want then you should be able to figure out how to do what you want to do from this example.

Please note, you find the element you want to append to **.find('#wrapleft')** and then you append the element you desire **.append($('#showlink'))**

```html
<body>
<div id="showlink"><a href="http://example.com">showlink</a></div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft"></div><div id="wrapright">This is text display by append</div></div></div>').find('#wrapleft').append($('#showlink'));
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: finding for wrapleft is not necessary, i found solution.what i searching for.https://jsfiddle.net/83fbnwe4/10/   arman did it..thanks for your support too.

Answer (score 1):

`append` takes more than just a html string. You can use an actual DOM element object, or a jQuery object. So get a reference to the element you want to move, a reference to the target element, and call the appropriate method

```
var showlink = jQuery("#showlink");
$('body').append('your previous code here');
//since the html is now in the dom you can get a reference to it
$("#wrapleft").append( showlink );
```

Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft"></div><div id="wrapright">This is text display by append</div></div></div>');
  var showlink = $("#showlink");
  $("#wrapleft").append( showlink );
  showlink.show(600);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showlink" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>
</div>
```

If you are actually wanting to do a string concatenation, although I don't see why you would want it over the previous method shown. Just use the reference to get the html and use it in the concatenation

```
var showlink = $("#showlink");
$('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft">'+(showlink[0].outerHTML)+'</div><div id="wrapright">This is text display by append</div></div></div>');
//remove the old showlink
showlink.remove();
```

Comment: man you are awesome to do that for me, your first code worked which you show the demo...it has solved my issue...however for instant i would just ask you, that it is never possible to add that script tag inside append body, as you place this >> var showlink = $("#showlink");
  $("#wrapleft").append( showlink );
  showlink.show(600); out the append body, this is not be possible to add the id showlink inside the primary append after wrapleft...i know you did it but you placed it outer from append...in next reply i will show you how i add the year tag inside append and worked it.

Comment: the solution given by arman here is what the exact solution i was looking for https://jsfiddle.net/83fbnwe4/10/ thanks for your support too...your script also worked for me..i will answered both of yours.thanks

Comment: @JohnBelly, Arman's solution is exactly what the second code example does, except their code only copies the inner html, and not the whole element.

Comment: your code and his code both is useful for me, it worked for me both..thank you so much for your effort...i almost spend much of time in resolving this issue, i left all my template work and was looking for this..think that i lost almost $40 because of now work since yesterday..i am really really thanks both of you.

Comment: Cool answer. You might want to add `$('#showlink').show();` to the bottom of the second answer. The link would not be visible otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a copy of the link `<a href="http://example.com">` in your new `<div id="wrapleft">`, you can use the `.html()` function: [JS Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/83fbnwe4/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft">' 
    + $("#showlink").html() 
    + '</div><div id="wrapright">This is text display by append</div></div></div>');
});
```

However, this one only copies the link and leaves the original copy and the `div#showlink` behind. If you would like to get rid of them, I would suggest you this: [JS Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/83fbnwe4/13/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $link = $("#showlink"),
        copy = $link.clone().removeAttr('style')[0].outerHTML;

  // We can append the copy inside #wrapleft (all at once, as you want it to be)
    $('body').append('<div id="wrap"><div id="wrapp-inner"><div id="wrapleft">' 
    + copy + '</div><div id="wrapright">This is text display by append</div></div></div>');

  // Now you can remove the original #showlink from your DOM
  $link.remove();

  // From this point on, $('#showlink') will select your new copy
  // Lets try increasing font size
  $('#showlink').css('fontSize','1.5em');

});
```